# Is there any source available to read more about O-clustering ? (Orthogonal Partitioning Clustering)

Tags: api, classification

I am interested in reading more about O-Cluster and unfortunately all the links I found only contain very small description of the algorithm and do not give details about how to implement it.

The most detailed link I found is this https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/datamine.111/b28129/algo_oc.htm#DMCON059

I need to write a detailed description of the algorithm until tomorrow and I am really stuck

Comment: Maybe better to ask at http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ (but then remove it here)?

Comment: Did you search Oracle support forums? They may not be indexed by search engines.

Comment: @JanDoggen  I will try it out of curiosity. However the professor allowed me to present a different algorithm so I solved the initial problem :)

Comment: I'm closing this question because the poster said the task is no longer needed, and also I find it off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

There is a cited reference paper in the link you provide

```
Campos, M.M., Milenova, B.L.
"O-Cluster: Scalable Clustering of Large High Dimensional Data Sets"
```

Unfortunately, the paper is behind a paywall and the link from Oracle goes to linkrot. I checked a few dates on the [wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130618202921/http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/advanced-analytics/odm/index.html?origref=http://web.archive.org/web/20130618202921/http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/bi/odm/) and they also are no good.

---

Perhaps of interest, this algorithm is also implemented in R-Stats

```
https://cran.r-project.org/package=RODM
```

- In the [PDF](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODM/RODM.pdf) reference manual you may find more technical details about the algorithm.